# Circular imports errors in splitting Pydantic Schemas in different files

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm quite new to Python and I'm building my first project with FastAPI.

I'm on Python 3.11.4, FastAPI 0.101.0, Pydantic 2.1.1.

I want to keep my codebase well organized so I set up a `usersDomain` folder where I will keep all the users related stuff.
Then I have subfolders for each entity (database table), e.g. `users` and `accounts`.
Each User can have multiple Accounts (to address different idps as email, Facebook, Google, etc..).

I'm facing circular import errors due to the relationship between to two table/schemas.
Someone could help me out in solving this? I'm used to statically typed language and this totally counter intuitive to me.
I've already tried several solutions found here on stackoverflow but none of them was successful

Below my users and accounts schemas:

```py
## users\schemas.py

from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from src.usersDomain.accounts.schemas import Account


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    primary_email: str
    creation_date: datetime

class UserCreate(UserBase):
    pass

class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    accounts: list[Account] = []
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

```py
## accounts\schemas.py

from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel

from src.usersDomain.users.schemas import User

class AccountBase(BaseModel):
    cognito_sub: str
    name: str
    family_name: str
    email: str
    phone_number: str
    picture: str
    identities: str
    token: str
    creation_date: datetime

    user: User

class AccountCreate(AccountBase):
    pass

class Account(AccountBase):
    pass

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

This is the error I got in the console:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from partially initialized module
'src.usersDomain.users.schemas' (most likely due to a circular import
(C:\Users\marco\git\excel-ha-sempre-ragione-api\src\usersDomain\users\schemas.py)
```

Comment: You already imported `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`, so use it. This will result in an error, namely `name 'Account' is not defined`. Either use a string (e.g. `'Account'`) or `from __future__ import annotations` to avoid this, as of right now, you're types are entangled in runtime which is avoided by the provided solutions.

Comment: I did use it unsuccesfully. I solved removing the Account dependency from the User Model.
As far as I could investigate, Pydantic has problems handling two way relationships (SQLAlchemy doesn't).